# Where is the source for parses ACL?

Tags: node.js, parse-platform

I'm looking at the parse server that was released, and looking at the spec I see a reference to methods:

```
        equal(object.getACL().getReadAccess(user), true);
        equal(object.getACL().getWriteAccess(user), true);
        equal(object.getACL().getPublicReadAccess(), false);
        equal(object.getACL().getPublicWriteAccess(), false);
        ok(object.get("ACL"));
```

I searched the repo and I don't see any ACL related classes and I couldn't find a relevant library in package.json that it might be using.

Where is it getting this functionality from?

Reference:
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/blob/master/spec/ParseACL.spec.js

Answer (score 1):

It comes from the parse package in NPM. See here for the method definition: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/blob/37f433152031cdb5c782d12fbcead2c97c49e0cf/src/ParseObject.js#L862

And here is the full ParseACL file: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/blob/37f433152031cdb5c782d12fbcead2c97c49e0cf/src/ParseACL.js

Comment: OK I was only looking at the parse-server code, which I thought was the only backend code to look at.  The parse sdk-JS before looking at it I would have though was just a client to the backend server.